# Consulta SQL básica

Tags: sql

Estoy haciendo un T.P que consta de una institución educativa terciaria que encomendó el desarrollo del modulo para el control de equivalencias. Donde necesito hacer unas dos consultas.

Primero Adjunto el PowerDesigner para saber como esta conformada la BDD.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1-Tengo que Mostrar las materias que generen mas de una equivalencia, mostrar Ent. Educativa, carrera, materia.

Nose como mostrar las dos universidades, las dos carreras y dos materias que tienen un alta porcentaje de equivalencia.... (TABLA EQUIVALENCIA.)

Con:

```
> Select * from equivalencia where observaciones_equi = 'Alto porcentaje'
```

Muestra los ID de cada Universidad, pero quiero mostrar los nombres...

El resultado debería de ser así, pero con la Descripción, en ves de los ID.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias!.

Comment: Los nombres de las universidades estan en otra tabla?  Si es asi, deberias de mostrar la estructura de las dos tablas en cuestion.

Comment: @alanfcm ahi esta, había olvidado de subir la captura

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
Select * From equivalencia Inner Join institucion 
              On equivalencia.id_ins = institucion.id_ins 
Where observaciones_equi = 'Alto porcentaje'
```

Comment: No conoce "e.id_ins"

Comment: Con que base de datos trabajas?

Comment: Estamos usando una maquina virtual, donde trabajamos con WinSQL (version vieja) y Paquete XAMMP. phpMyAdmin 2.11

Comment: Ya edite.  Intentalo asi.

Comment: Tampoco Alan, mi duda es, como relaciono el inner join con Equivalencia y materia. Al tener varias claves foráneas no se como consultar. 

Igualmente el resultado deberia de ser:

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es armar la tabla extendida desde la tabla "EQUIVALENCIAS" (tu tabla base) hasta INSTITUCION, recorriendo las demas tablas en caso de querer usar las columnas secundarias de cada una.

```
SELECT i.nombre_ins, c.nombre_carrera, m.nombre_materia, e.porcentaje_equi
FROM equivalencia as e
INNER JOIN materia as m on (e.id_ins = m.id_ins AND e.id_carrera = m.id_carrera AND e.id_materia = m.id_materia)
INNER JOIN carrera as c on (e.id_ins = m.id_ins ADN e.id_carrera = c.id_carrera)
INNER JOIN institucion as i on (e.id_ins = i.id_ins)
WHERE e.observaciones_equi = 'Alto porcentaje'
```

Ya con esta sentencia, deberías poder utilizar los demás campos en cada tabla. En caso de no ser así revisar el uso de **LEFT JOIN** o **FULL OUTER JOIN**, para las relaciones entre tablas.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias igualmente por su tiempo!